# httpurlconnection not receiving response from server

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

In my project I am using **HttpURLConnection** for post data.
The data is posted successfully, but I'm not receiving server response.

Here is my code:

```
try {
                // httpurlconnection post data
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                out.print(urlParameters);
                out.close();

                //build the string to store the response text from the server
                String content = "";
                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 201) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
                    ErrorClass error = new Gson().fromJson(br, ErrorClass.class);
                    // throw the error message to the application
                    throw new Exception(content);
                }
                return content;
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
```

Comment: can you add the server endpoint please? or is it private

Comment: I have added the server response

Comment: maybe this will help: https://github.com/pepperonas/AppRegistry

Comment: You haven't provide the whole code. Do you get any error messages on the server side? Do you at least see on the server that the request arrives?